# How to use CSS to set height of image the same as width

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, css-position

In my project, there are some images. My code looks like:

```
<div className="col-sm-6">
   <img src="xxx">
</div>
<div className="col-sm-6">
   <img src="xxx">
</div>
```

The width of `img` is 100% of `div`, which is 50% of the whole screen. If I resize the browser, the width of image is changed. In this case, how to keep the height is still the same as width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the aspect ratio of the image.

1. If you want to stretch the image to a square: since the container `<div>` is 50% of the whole screen. You could've written it as `width: 50vw;` *(50% of the viewport width)*. The same for your image: `width: 50vw;` and to keep height the same as the width.:

```css
.col-sm-6 img {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
}
```

2. If the image is a square, just adjust width. Height will automatically adapt. Since you must be using **Bootstrap** *(guessing from the class name col-sm-6)*.
3. If the image is always panoramic:

```css
.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid lime;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg">
</div>
```

4. Same logic above for always vertical images.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the width of the `wrapper` to equal `width` and `height` for this and 100% `width` and `height` for the `img`.

**Another Option**

You can also use the fact that `padding` is always calculated based on the `width` in CSS-

1. Position the `img` *absolutely* relative to its *wrapper*
2. Give the *same* value for `padding-top` and `width` (50vw each) and set `height` to zero for the `wrapper`.
3. Give `width: 100%` for the `img`

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 50vw;
  height:0;
  padding-top: 50vw;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper img {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
</div>
```

Note that your images may stretch out if it is *not* a square image - you can *opt* according to your design to drop either of `width: 100%` or `height: 100%` so that the stretching won't happen. (or opt to use a square image of course!)

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 50vw;
  height:0;
  padding-top: 50vw;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper img {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually if the width auto then height fix hardware and vice versa, if you want auto height to auto-height of the current div